# Unable to run get_url module with ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have started to learn Ansible watching online vids . But got stuck at the first step when creating and running a simple playbook.

When I run below playbook as below ->
$ ansible-playbook download.yml

Then output displayed is ->

*ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed in this context
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/download.yml': line 3, column 11, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.                       The offending line appears to be:*

-name: Test
   get_url:
          ^ here

Below are the contents of my playbook download.yml ->

```
tasks: 
 -name: Test
  get_url:
   url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini
   dest: /home/sunny/ec2.ini
   mode: 700
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3):

**Space behind the dash** in name is missing. Instead of

```yaml
-name: Test
```

the correct syntax is

```yaml
- name: Test
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Vladimir !! Thanks for helping me to run my first playbook :)